Can we delete the Public IP address created along with Azure Databricks manage resource group? Our databricks is set toNo public IP - Yes
We have enabled secure cluster connectivity in our Azure Databricks. Hence, Enable No Public IP - is set to True. However, we see that a public IP address created within the auto-created databricks managed resource group. We want to understand the impact if we delete this IP public address.
We want to understand the impact if we delete this IP public address.

Can you explain your issue with an example and any errors?
